# Not sure why I am getting different lengths when using a string or a char

Tags: c++, linux, string, char

When I call gethostname using a char my length 25 but when I use a string my length is 64.  Not really sure why.  Both of them I am declaring the same size on HOST_NAME_MAX.

```
        char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
        BOOL host =  gethostname(hostname, sizeof hostname);
        expectedComputerName = hostname;
        int size2 = expectedComputerName.length();

        std::string test(HOST_NAME_MAX, 0);
        host =  gethostname(&test[0], test.length());
        int  testSize = test.length();
```

Comment: There's a difference between `sizeof` and `std::string::length()`

Comment: @erip Yes but that is not relevant to this example

Answer (score 5):

An `std::string` object can contain `NUL`s (i.e. `'\0'` characters). You are storing the name in the first bytes of a string object that was created with a size of `HOST_NAME_MAX` length.

Storing something in the beginning of the string data won't change the length of the string that remains therefore `HOST_NAME_MAX`.

When creating a string from a char pointer instead the `std::string` object created will contain up to, but excluding, the first `NUL` character (`0x00`). The reason is that a C string cannot contain `NUL`s because the first `NUL` is used to mark the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

Consider what you're doing in each case. In the former code snippet, you're declaring a character array capable of holding `HOST_NAME_MAX`-1 characters (1 for the null terminator). You then load some string data into that buffer via the call to `gethostname` and then print out the length of buffer by assigning it to a `std::string` object using `std::string::operator=` that takes a `const char *`. One of the effects of this is that it will change an internal size variable of `std::string` to be `strlen` of the buffer, which is not necessarily the same as `HOST_NAME_MAX`. A call to `std::string::length` simply returns that variable.

In the latter case, you're using the `std::string` constructor that takes a *size* and initial character to construct `test`. This constructor sets the internal size variable to whatever size you passed in, which is `HOST_NAME_MAX`. The fact that you then copy in some data to `std::string`s  internal buffer has no bearing on its size variable. As with the other case, a call to the `length()` member function simply returns the size  - which is `HOST_NAME_MAX` - regardless of whether or not the actual length of the underlying buffer is smaller than `HOST_NAME_MAX`.

As @MattMcNabb mentioned in the comments, you could fix this by:

```
test.resize( strlen(test.c_str()) );
```

Why might you want to do this? Consistency with the char buffer approach might be a reason, but another reason may be performance oriented. In the latter case you're not only outright setting the length of the string to `HOST_NAME_MAX`, but *also* its capacity (omitting the SSO for brevity), which you can find starting on line 242 of [libstdc++'s std::string implementation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/libstdc++/api/a00754_source.html).  What this means in terms of performance is that even though only, say, 25 characters are *actually* in your `test` string, the next time you append to that string (via `+=`,`std::string::append`,etc), it's more than likely to have to reallocate and grow the string, [as shown here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f2e5aad208b1a364), because the internal size and internal capacity are equal. Following @MattMcNabb's suggestion, however, the string's internal size is reduced down to the length of the actual payload, while keeping the capacity the same as before, and you avoid the almost immediate re-growth and re-copy of the string, [as shown here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27fd22db1353de2c).

Comment: To fix this we need `test.resize( strlen(test.c_str()) );`, assuming that this "gethostname" function writes a null-terminated string.